# while loop python zip sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-3.x

I am .NET developer. I am facing difficulty in converting a python code to javascript. I have gone through the documentation too but still not able to understand.

Following is the line of code I want to convert into Javascript.

```
while sum([a - b for a, b in zip(rad0, rad1)]) != 0:
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: That python could be written as `while sum(rad0) != sum(rad1):`

Comment: can you please explain a bit. As per your description I assume that
total of rad0 list is not equal to total of rad1.

Am I right?

Comment: The sum of the differences of each element is the same as the difference of the sum of all the elements (zip pairs the elements, the `a-b` subtracts them the whole thing in brackets is a list comprehension).  The code only wants to execute the body of the while when the difference is not zero.  That means it only wants to execute when the sums are different.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks a lot, highly appreciated. I am .NET guy so it was not clear to me.

Comment: The only wrinkle that `while sum(rad0) != sum(rad1):` misses is that `zip` will truncate its result to the length of the shorter iterator.  so if `rad0` has 3 elements and `rad1` has 4 elements my simplification won't work.

Comment: The python person wasn't writing clear python.

Comment: I have equal number of elements so that will not be an issue for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101000/discussion-between-manoj-sethi-and-steven-rumbalski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum([a - b for a, b in zip(rad0, rad1)]) != 0:
```

`zip` pairs each element of `rad0` with `rad1`.  If the iterables are of differing length, the result is truncated to length of the shorter iterable.

The stuff in brackets is a list comprehension.  It iterates over each pair created by `zip`, assigns them to `a` and `b`, performs `a - b`, and collects the result in a list.

`sum` totals the resulting list. `!= 0` checks that the sum is not equal to zero.

If the iterables `rad0` and `rad1` are the same length the python can be simplified to

```
while sum(rad0) - sum(rad1) != 0:
```

This is because the sum of the differences of each element is the same as the difference of the sum of all the elements.  And since we only want to iterate when the difference is not zero, we also only want to iterate when the sums are not equal:

```
while sum(rad0) != sum(rad1):
```